# Raster layer calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, geoprocessing, raster-calculator

In PCI Geomatic, I have two raster layer.raster1 identified like %1 and raster2 like %2.

```
if (%1 <= 10) then 
   %2 = 60
elseif (%1 > 10 and %1 <=50) then 
  %2=80
elseif (%1 > 50 and %1 <=90) then 
  %2=120
else
  %2=0
endif
```

Please, How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: ("COUCHE12D@1" <= 189)*10 +
("COUCHE12D@1" > 189 AND "COUCHE12D@1" <=214 )*20 +
("COUCHE12D@1" > 214 AND "COUCHE12D@1" <=239 )*30 +
("COUCHE12D@1" > 239)*40 BUT DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Raster Calculator`,`raster2` should be:

```
("raster1@1">=10)*60+("raster1@1">10 AND "raster1@1"<=50 )*80+("raster1@1">50 AND "raster1@1"<=90)*120
```